# I need help to design a 'Income' type textfield using JavaScript using conditions

Tags: javascript

For example a correct format will be `2,545.39`.

The user must not to be able to enter anything except for what is show above.

The user must also enter in a valid input, for example a user can't enter in a value such as `002453.23`, so they can't have 2 `0`'s next to each other.

Comment: Use regex to validate numbers, alternativly. if you are using jQuery then please see this: https://www.customd.com/articles/14/jquery-number-format-redux

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/i;
var key = $('textbox').val();

if ((key.match(regex) != null) || (parseInt(key) != 0)) {
    $('textbox').val(key.replace(/^0+/, ''));
    alert('legal');
}
else {    
    alert('illegal');
}
```